# Using AlarmManagerCompat Support Library

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

If one uses the AlarmManagerCompat Class of the Support Library android.support.v4.app.AlarmManagerCompat, can one call the Alarm using the single syntax below (which would be applicable to all devices, regardless of the API level installed, the Support Library providing the backward compatibility for all previous versions of the API):

```
alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
```

Or one still has to verify the API level installed on the device first, and then call the Alarm using the appropriate syntax based on the API level used, such as the following:

```
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntentMain);
            // Adding manual re-scheduling for repetition
        }
        else if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntentMain);
            // Adding manual re-scheduling for repetition
        }
        else if (VERSION.SDK_INT <= 18) {
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000, alarmIntentMain);
        }
```

From my understanding, the Support Libraries are meant to have the ability to use a more recent Class with older versions of the API without having to write different syntaxes of the same functionality for different APIs. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the [source code for AlarmManagerCompat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/compat/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app/AlarmManagerCompat.java#219), it does exactly the API level checks you stated:

```
public static void setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(@NonNull AlarmManager alarmManager, int type,
        long triggerAtMillis, @NonNull PendingIntent operation) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(type, triggerAtMillis, operation);
    } else {
        AlarmManagerCompat.setExact(alarmManager, type, triggerAtMillis, operation);
    }
}

public static void setExact(@NonNull AlarmManager alarmManager, int type, long triggerAtMillis,
        @NonNull PendingIntent operation) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        alarmManager.setExact(type, triggerAtMillis, operation);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(type, triggerAtMillis, operation);
    }
}
```

So you can use `AlarmManagerCompat` without having to worry about API levels.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time Ianhanniballake.